# SearchView that shows items related to the search term

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, searchview

How can I have a search function in android that will show items similar to what the user typed in? For example:

I have the items Distance, Tax, and Color.
If the user types Kilometer, Mi, or distance, show "distance";
If the user types Tax, Money, or Bill, show "tax";
If the user types HEX, RGB, or Color, show "color"

For now, I have this:

```kotlin
val applets = arrayOf("distance","tax","color")
val conversionsLength = this.resources.getStringArray(R.array.conversionsLength)

val appletAdapter : ArrayAdapter<String> = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, applets)

binding.appletList.adapter = appletAdapter
binding.searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
    override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String): Boolean { binding.searchView.clearFocus(); return false }
    
    override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String): Boolean {
        if (applets.joinToString("\n").contains(newText))
        {
            appletAdapter.filter.filter(newText)
        }
        if (conversionsLength.joinToString("\n").contains(newText))
        {
            //TODO appletAdapter.add("distance") didn't work
        }
        else appletAdapter.filter.filter(applets.joinToString("\n"))
        return false
    }
})
```

What can I do in `//TODO` to so that apart from the items that were filtered with the first `contains()`, it *also* shows the string I want it to show

Comment: What you can get from a `SearchView` is a `String` so the easiest way will be to compare strings, for example you can check if the entered string `contains`  `kilometer` then do the search  in the kilometers column and return the matched results.

Comment: thanks @Jagar! How do you think I could go about it? As shown above, I tried using `appletAdapter.add("distance")` but that didn't work.

Comment: create a string arraylist for each of the three items; each array includes the words that describes it for example, "mi", "km", and so on for distance, then in `onQueryTextSubmit` check if the query contains any item of any of the three arrays, and returns the value if one of its array items was contained; here it may returns more than one array too; if query for example has "km" and "red"

Comment: Thanks :)
Yep, that's what I'm doing with the `if (conversionsLength.joinToString("\n").contains(newText))`, but I don't know what to do so that the ListView actually displays length when I type km or mi. It seems that ArrayAdapters can only filter one string. I presume that  `appletAdapter.add("distance")` didn't work because it is also being filtered, plus even if it did work, there would be two "distance" in the ListView

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite understand the question, but I have this.
You must have some arrays with the searched matches, for example:

```
val distance_matches = listOf("Kilometer", "Mi", "distance")

val tax_matches = listOf("Tax", "Money", "Bill")

val color_matches = listOf("HEX", "RGB", "Color")

onTextChange(newText: String) : Boolean {
    if (newText in distance_matches) {
       //FILTER DISTANCE
       return true
    }

    if (newText in tax_matches) {
       //FILTER TAX
       return true
    }

    if (newText in color_matches) {
       //FILTER COLOR
       return true
    }
}
```

But for them to match well, the matches must be the same as the entered text.
I hope it's what what you occupied